# Неправильно отображаются юникод-символы в полях типа VARCHAR

Tags: mysql, sql, кодировка, utf-8

С помощью LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE загрузил в БД список русских слов. Загружал из файла с кодировкой utf8. Теперь русские слова почему-то неправильно отображаются неправильно:
[image: Русские буквы в phpmyadmin]

Аналогичная ситуация и в консоли при попытке сделать SELECT * FROM.
Пробовал решить с помощью:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
SET collation_connection='utf8_general_ci;
SET collation_server='utf8_general_ci';
SET character_set_client='utf8';
SET character_set_connection='utf8';
SET character_set_results='utf8';
SET character_set_server='utf8';
```

Answer (score 1):

Собсвенно, пока писал вопрос - нашел ответ. При использовании LOAD DATA нужно указать CHARACTER SET - utf8. Общий синтаксис:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file'
IGNORE INTO TABLE table
CHARACTER SET UTF8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

И в моём случае:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/1.txt' 
CHARACTER SET UTF8 
INTO TABLE words;
```

[image: Слова отображаются правильно]